# Rails 5, Bootstrap Carousel not rendering - setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im trying to use an image carousel in my Rails 5 app.  I'm trying to follow the approach in this article: https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-helper-bootstrap-carousel

I have an models for proposal and image. The associations are:

Proposal

```
has_many :images, as: :imageable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Image

```
belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true
```

My view partial has:

```
    <!-- GALLERY -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> -->
 <% @images.each do |gallery| %>
    <% if gallery == @images.order(created_at: :asc).first%>
    <div class="item active">
     <%= carousel_for(gallery) %>
       <%= image_tag(gallery.picture.url, :class => "carousel_image", :style => "text-align: center" ) %> 
        <div class="carousel_caption">
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= gallery.comment.humanize %></p>  
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= gallery.credit %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% else %>
     <div class="item">
    <%= carousel_for(gallery) %>
     <%= image_tag(gallery.picture, :class => "carousel_image") %>
      <div class="carousel_caption">
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= gallery.comment.humanize %></p>  
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= gallery.credit %></p>
      </div>
    </div> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<!-- </div> -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /GALLERY -->
```

Helper has:

```
module CarouselHelper
  def carousel_for(images)
    Carousel.new(self, images).html
  end

  class Carousel
    def initialize(view, images)
      @view, @images = view, images
      @uid = SecureRandom.hex(6)
    end

    def html
      content = safe_join([indicators, slides, controls])
      content_tag(:div, content, id: uid, class: 'carousel slide')
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :view, :images, :uid
    delegate :link_to, :content_tag, :image_tag, :safe_join, to: :view

    def indicators
      items = images.count.times.map { |index| indicator_tag(index) }
      content_tag(:ol, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-indicators')
    end

    def indicator_tag(index)
      options = {
        class: (index.zero? ? 'active' : ''),
        data: { 
          target: uid, 
          slide_to: index
        }
      }

      content_tag(:li, '', options)
    end

    def slides
      items = images.map.with_index { |image, index| slide_tag(image, index.zero?) }
      content_tag(:div, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-inner')
    end

    def slide_tag(image, is_active)
      options = {
        class: (is_active ? 'item active' : 'item'),
      }

      content_tag(:div, image_tag(image), options)
    end

    def controls
      safe_join([control_tag('left'), control_tag('right')])
    end

    def control_tag(direction)
      options = {
        class: "#{direction} carousel-control",
        data: { slide: direction == 'left' ? 'prev' : 'next' }
      }

      icon = content_tag(:i, '', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-#{direction}")
      control = link_to(icon, "##{uid}", options)
    end
  end
end
```

My application.js has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require markerclusterer
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `count' for #<Image:0x007fb10c88bea8>
```

It highlights this line of the carousel (indicators method):

```
  items = images.count.times.map { |index| indicator_tag(index) }
```

**ARUN'S SUGGESTION**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> -->
 <%# @images.each do |gallery| %>
    <%# if gallery == @images.order(created_at: :asc).first%>
    <div class="item active">
     <%= carousel_for(@images) %>
       <%= image_tag(@image.picture.url, :class => "carousel_image", :style => "text-align: center" ) %> 
        <div class="carousel_caption">
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.comment.humanize %></p>  
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.credit %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%# else %>
     <div class="item">
    <%= carousel_for(@images) %>
     <%= image_tag(@image.picture, :class => "carousel_image") %>
      <div class="carousel_caption">
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.comment.humanize %></p>  
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.credit %></p>
      </div>
    </div> 
  <%# end %>
<%# end %>
<!-- </div> -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /GALLERY -->
```

ERROR SAYS: undefined method `picture' for nil:NilClass

**2nd attempt at Arun's suggestion**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="item active">
     <%= carousel_for(@images) %>
       <%= image_tag(@image.picture.url, :class => "carousel_image", :style => "text-align: center" ) %> 
        <div class="carousel_caption">
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.comment.humanize %></p>  
            <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.credit %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="item">
    <%= carousel_for(@images) %>
     <%= image_tag(@image.picture.url, :class => "carousel_image") %>
      <div class="carousel_caption">
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.comment.humanize %></p>  
        <p style="text-align: center"><%= @image.credit %></p>
      </div>
    </div> 
<!-- </div> -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /GALLERY -->
```

Error says: undefined method `picture' for nil:NilClass

**Arun's revised suggestion**

Taking Arun's revised suggestion, I try replacing the entire gallery view, with:

```
<%= carousel_for(Image.all.map(&:picture_url)) %>
```

When i try to render the page, the first image is rendered. I can see from the chrome inspector, that the second image is recognised, although the carousel doesnt work. The chevrons don't move the images along. There are no js issues showing in the console.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@images.count.times.map { |index| indicator_tag(index) }`?

Comment: I get the same error with @images

Comment: Why don't you post the code which has the error? Post the contents of the helper file so that we can what's going on.

Comment: Sorry - I cut it to move it & didn't paste

Comment: Hey all, I'm the author of the article on the carousel helper. Couple things (1) the call to `carousel_for` should be the only thing in the view; the helper spits out the HTML markup so you should not also include it manually (2) you should be passing an array of image URLs to the helper; that is an array of string URLs. If the carousel does not *function* then make sure Bootstrap is loaded and working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your javascript and jquery for this carousel to work properly.

In the end of your html file, add this code (it can be before the /body):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
  $('#mycarousel').carousel();
  });
</script>
```

You can also create a partial with this code and call it on the end of your application layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you're calling `carousel_for` method. You should be passing an array of images but you're passing a single instance of `Image` type as you're iterating over `@images`.

ie. `images` inside the `Carousel` class is not an `ActiveRecord Relation`. So, you can't call the `count` method. The error message clearly says that you're trying to invoke the `count` on an `image` instance.

So, you should pass `@images` to `carousel_for`. Your view should only contain

```
carousel_for(@images)
```

**EDIT**

You should actually pass the array of image URLs to the `carousel_for` method.

```
<%= carousel_for(Image.all.pluck(&:picture_url)) %>
```

Comment: I tried that suggestion (copied to the  post). It doesnt work, but also, how does the first image get separated out from the rest so that it can be the active image?

Comment: @Mel Updated my answer. You have to collect the image URLs from the `@images` collection and then pass it to the helper.

Comment: I still don't understand. I'll copy the updated attempt (deleting the commented bits)

Comment: @Mel Delete everything from the view. Your view should only contain `carousel_for(image_urls)`

Comment: That gives this error: undefined local variable or method `image_urls' for #<#<Class:0x007fb127c9bfa0>:0x007fb10bd21360>
Did you mean?  image_url

Comment: When I try: <%= carousel_for(image_url) %>
     
the error gives wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)

Comment: My bad. I should have been clear. You should retrieve the image_urls from `@images` and then pass it as an argument to the helper method. I still don't understand why you have the html in your view.

Comment: Still don't understand that. How do I retrieve the image urls from images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127428/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-mel).